# Getting cookie values and use it in ExpressionEngine Templates

Tags: expressionengine

I would like to use some stored cookie values in my ExpressionEngine templates without using any PHP.

My current template code

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="favorites" category="<?php echo $COOKIE['favorite']?>"}
{title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This is ugly and doesn't perform that well under load.
Any suggestions? Maybe an addon?

Comment: It's also really bad security, since cookies should be treated as user input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set cookies in EE with the set_cookie() method in the Functions class.

http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/reference/functions.html#set-cookie-name-string-value-string-expire-int

```
$this->EE->functions->set_cookie('your_cookie_name', 'some_value', 3600 * 24) // Set a cookie that expires in 1 day

$this->EE->input->cookie('your_cookie_name'); // returns 'some_value';
```

EE Add-on from Devot:ee

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cookies